# Workflow - Error - Visualforce email template - External image

Tags: visualforce, email, workflow, template, image-formula

I'm getting a weird error when trying to use my workflow to send out a visualforce email template.
The visualforce email template generates a PDF attachment (from VF component) and works fine when I send and test merge fields etc.
So i set up a workflow based on a field update to send out this email to all related contacts of the custom object; when I tick the field and click save it doesn't allow me to save the records and throws this error:

*Unable to Finish Processing Request
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact support@salesforce.com. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 
Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
Error ID: Data Not Available*

I've done some troubleshooting myself and have identified the root of the problem.
In my PDF attachment, I display a QR code at the bottom. when I take this out the workflow works fine.
The QR code is created in a custom field (formula(TEXT)) using a free QR code API site
"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=75x75&data="

The site is added in remote sites.

Everything has worked fine so far and the QR code hasn't had any issues displaying. It's only when I try to trigger the workflow it fails.

I've also tried using any other external image, whilst adding in the matching site in remote sites; and still get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to break down this updating fields and sending emails into two parts.

Through workflow, just update the field.

Through separate process builder, send the email. You should fire the process builder, based on field value changes.

Since, sending emails is considered as webservice callout, so committing the data and callout could not be in same transaction through workflow in single goal.

Comment: I have tried separating out the process as you have suggested. 
Workflow updates a field; based on me ticking another field.
Process builder fires when this new field is updated.

Same error message as before and doesn't let me even save the record

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while sending email based on VisualForce Email Template, where the VF Component inside was performing a callout.
When I tested the template, it worked, but when i sent it by code, i got error: "FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error".

The solution was to use renderStoredEmailTemplate and after that - send the message.
(Instead of just set the templateId etc.).